# Parsing query string with custom aggregation, using Search API

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, opendatasoft

I've installed a plugin to elastic (https://github.com/opendatasoft/elasticsearch-aggregation-geoclustering) and I have an endpoint (high level rest client) that takes an ES query body string and builds it with SearchSourceBuilder.

Using kibana, the plugin works fine:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "clusters": {
      "geo_point_clustering": {
        "field": "geo.point",
        "zoom": 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I get the expected result.

However, the SearchSourceBuilder have trouble parsing the "geo_point_clustering" aggregation

Exception:

```
threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is ParsingException[Unknown aggregation type [geo_point_clustering]]; nested: NamedObjectNotFoundException[[31:30] unknown field [geo_point_clustering]];] with root cause
```

The exception comes from where the request body is converted into a SearchSourceBuilder

```
val searchSourceBuilder = SearchSourceBuilder().timeout(TimeValue(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
val searchModule = SearchModule(Settings.EMPTY, false, emptyList())
val xContentRegistry = NamedXContentRegistry(searchModule.namedXContents)
searchSourceBuilder.parseXContent(
  XContentFactory.xContent(XContentType.JSON)
    .createParser(xContentRegistry,
      DeprecationHandler.THROW_UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, body)
)
```

So my question is (i think) how can I add the custom aggregation type to this parser?

Thanks!